# dictionary of dictionaries melted dataframes, plot multiple bar plots together on same graph

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dictionary of dictionaries like so:

```
model_metrics = {
    "model_1": {"AA": 0.01241651, "BB": 0.04135146, "CC": 0.65164441, "DD": 0.516411451},
    "model_2": {"AA": 0.14216511, "BB": 0.07651312, "CC": 0.59598435, "DD": 0.554684131}, 
    "model_3": {"AA": 0.04411651, "BB": 0.09684354, "CC": 0.75613541, "DD": 0.651111451},
}
```

I created this function to graph out each separate model:

```
def graph_fun1(model_metrics):
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns
    fig2, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1)
    fig2.subplots_adjust(bottom=1, top=3, hspace=0.5)
    recommender_palette = ["#ED2BFF", "#14E2C0", "#FF9F1C", "#5E2BFF","#FC5FA3"]
    sns.set_palette(recommender_palette)
    
    count = 0
    for key, value in model_metrics.items():
        imp_metrics = pd.melt((pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=value, orient='index', columns=[key]).T), 
                value_vars=['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD'], var_name='metrics', value_name='values')
        splot = sns.barplot(data=imp_metrics, x="metrics", y="values", ax=axes[count])
        splot.set(ylim=(0, 1))
        for p in splot.patches:
            splot.annotate(format(p.get_height(), '.5f'), 
            (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()), 
            ha = 'center', va = 'center', 
            xytext = (0, 9), 
            textcoords = 'offset points')
        axes[count].set_title(f'{key}')
        count += 1
    return plt.show()
```

which generates this output:

[image]

I was instructed to put all the bars together on one graph. Basically one plot with all the same corresponding metrics values from each model side by side. From the dictionary, I would want to generate 12 bars all side by side and somehow color code them by model key.

Comment: What exactly is your question about this task?

Comment: How do I put all the bars side by side on one plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already import pandas, let's try:

```
splot = df.plot.bar(width=0.8)
for p in splot.patches:
    splot.annotate(format(p.get_height(), '.5f'), 
    (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()), 
    ha = 'center', va = 'center', 
    xytext = (0, 9), 
    textcoords = 'offset points')
```

Output:

[image]

---

**Update**: Using `seaborn` and a function:

```
def graph_fun1(model_metrics):
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns
    
    recommender_palette = ["#ED2BFF", "#14E2C0", "#FF9F1C", "#5E2BFF","#FC5FA3"]
    sns.set_palette(recommender_palette)
    fig2, ax = plt.subplots()
    
    imp_metrics = (pd.DataFrame(model_metrics).stack()
                     .rename_axis(index=['metrics','models'])
                     .reset_index(name='value')
                  )    
    sns.barplot(data=imp_metrics,x='metrics',y='value',hue='models',dodge=True)
    for p in ax.patches:
        ax.annotate(format(p.get_height(), '.5f'), 
                    (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()), 
                    ha = 'center', va = 'center', 
                    xytext = (0, 9), textcoords = 'offset points')

    plt.show()

graph_fun1(model_metrics)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to do it with seaborn? also I have to keep it in a function like I posted above.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. This looks great and is exactly what I was looking for. I will study what you did with 'stack()' and 'dodge'. Cheers

Comment: Can I ask you another question? When you use `stack()`, that moves the 'model' column into a MultiIndex alongside the 'metrics' index. I see why you used `rename_axis()` to rename the multiIndex of 'metrics, models'. This leaves the 'values' column to the side. In this case, the 'values' column becomes a series with the other two columns as an index? So thats how the machine knows to name that series to 'values' with `reset_index(name='values')` ?